# Panel activated/deactivated by Raycast, Deactivation not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hiya I wrote this code and am having issues with deactivating my panel when the raycast hovers away. Works perfectly when hovering over. I have no idea how to fix this error.
Thanks in advance

```
public Ray handRay;
private RaycastHit hit;
public GameObject myPanel;


void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, forward, Color.green);

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, (forward), out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Head")
        {
            myPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (hit.collider.tag != "Head")
        {
            myPanel.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than the else If is unnecessary you probably just want else. As you may not be over anything at all

Answer (score 1):

Fixed- for anyone wanting to implement this

public class RayCastPanelActive : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public Ray handRay;
private RaycastHit hit;
public GameObject myPanel;


void FixedUpdate()
{
     RaycastHit hit;
     Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
        //Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, forward, Color.green);

     if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, (forward), out hit))
     {

         if (hit.collider.tag == "Head")
         {
            myPanel.SetActive(true);
            print(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
             
         }

     }
    else
         {
             myPanel.SetActive(false);
         }
        
    
         
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Put a debug statement inside both your if and else. That way you will know what you are hitting with your Raycast.

Also like BugFinder says you want only else.

Comment: Hi, I added a debug. It identifies the object it hit as correctly, it doesn't seem to update when it isn't hitting anything.

Comment: ''Also like BugFinder says you want only else.'' I don't fully understand what you mean by this, could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you figured it out, but for anyone else who hits this problem, Unity's behavior inside a failed raycast has changed over the years.

These days, you should also be able to check hit for a null.

And Hit.collider should be throwing an error if hit is null.

Checking the result of the Physics.Raycast is the way to go though.